# Why is there elif in python?

Tags: python

So I am slightly confused as to the purpose of having `elif` in Python. Is `elif` a way to shorten `else if`? Which is more Pythonic `elif` or another `if` statement? Why is there elif in Python but not in something like Java?

Thanks for helping me to understand the gem of a language that is Python better.

Comment: There is no `else if` in `python`. It is `elif`. Please see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#elif

Comment: try compiling else if, see what happens :)

Comment: But there is no `else if` in Python...

Comment: There's `else: if`, but that's just putting a new `if` statement in an `else` block, which is a natural consequence of allowing arbitrary statements as the body of an `if/elif/else` statement.

Comment: from the docs: _Similar to the else, the elif statement is optional. However, unlike else, for which there can be at most one statement, there can be an arbitrary number of elif statements following an if_.

Comment: There's no possible answer to your question since python does NOT have a "else if" syntax (try it by yourself, it raises a `SyntaxError`).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers This question, while showing some misunderstanding, does get to the heart of the formal syntax of python and some design decisions behind it. The intent is clear and answerable.

Comment: @munk the question being "why does python has both elif and else if" and python not having "else if" ("else: if" being something different), I fail to see how it could be answered.  Your answer is based on the assumption that the OP actually asked "why does python have elif instead of else if", which is a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has `elif` to make parsing easier. One of the design goals of the syntax was to keep the parser simpler than other languages which require context free grammars. Faster parsing means a faster interpreter.

If I have `else if`, I don't know what the else means until I reach the if. To write this in python, I actually need to say

```
if cond1:
    ...
else:
    if cond2:
        ...
```

With `elif`, I have a single symbol which is unambiguous.

Functionally, these two statements are the same:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...     if x == 1:
...         return 1
...     else:
...         if x == 2:
...             return 2
... 

>>> def bar(x):
...     if x == 1:
...         return 1
...     elif x == 2:
...         return 2
...

>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

  3          12 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        

  5     >>   16 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             19 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             22 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             25 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       32

  6          28 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             31 RETURN_VALUE        
        >>   32 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             35 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

  3          12 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        

  4     >>   16 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             19 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             22 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             25 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       32

  5          28 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             31 RETURN_VALUE        
        >>   32 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             35 RETURN_VALUE
```